# React component is not being rendered

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm just starting to learn react and I don't understand why this is happening. My code is just to create a random number and display it in the DOM, then say that the number is a big number or a small number.

I have react-dom, react and Babel added to my script. [Here's](https://codepen.io/sarveshmd/pen/QWvjJxa) my codepen.

Here's my HTML Code.

```
<div id="root"></div>
<div id="rand"></div>
```

Here's my JavaScript code. The rand component is not being rendered when I have the `<p>{bigOrSmall} Number !</p>`. When I remove this line, It works and the random number `Your Random Number : [anything]` is shown.

```
const Head = () => {
  return <h1>Random Number</h1>
}
const RandomNum = () => {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  if (rand >= 5) {
    const bigOrSmall = "Big"
  }
  else {
   const bigOrSmall = "Small" 
  }
  return (
    <>
      <p>Your Number is: {rand}</p>
      <p>{bigOrSmall} Number !</p>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Head/>, document.getElementById("root"))
ReactDOM.render(<RandomNum/>, document.getElementById("rand"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have a scoping error in your `RandomNum` component. You need to define `bigOrSmall` outside of your `if` statement. The following will work:

```
const RandomNum = () => {
  let bigOrSmall;
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  if (rand >= 5) {
    bigOrSmall = "Big"
  }
  else {
    bigOrSmall = "Small" 
  }
  return (
    <>
      <p>Your Number is: {rand}</p>
      <p>{bigOrSmall} Number !</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

const is block scoped. So your variable is not accessible outside the curly braces.

Use `let bigOrSmall;` above the curly braces and inside manipulate their values.

When you move your variable outside, now its scope is the curly braces of the function component starting after `Random = () => {` and ending in the last line `}`.